# scroll to a div id which is comming after infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, ajax

hello all i have a page where there are some links which sends the user to respected pages and when the user gets on that page the page is scrolled to a div whose id is in the link like.

the link: mypage.php?scrollto=divno401 when the user reaches the page mypage it is scrolled to the div whise id is 401. the code is working fine when the that div is in the page but when the div is coming after infinite scroll (scrolling the page to the bottom more divs are appended to mypage) the page dosent scrolls.

say the link is mypage.php?scrollto=divno401 and the mypage.php have div only till 350 and div no 401 comes after scrolling the page to the bottom.

this is the code which is on the page mypage.php

```
 <?php
 $getdivno=$_GET['divno'];
 if($getdivno !='') { ?>
     <script>
         var thediv=$("#divnois"+"<?=$getdivno?>");
         if (thediv.length !== 0){
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: thediv.offset().top},
             'slow');
         }
         if (thediv.length === 0){ 
             $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
             $("#njtpostno70").css("background","red");
         } 
     </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

the divs are given id which is like divnois401

```
  <div id="divnois401"> </div>
```

Comment: Make sure your "infinite scroll" div has a fixed height.

Comment: how can it have a fixed height the div appends when the page goes to bottom . i mean how will i know what to put its height ?

Comment: Make the div a fixed height - any height, really - you can do 100%, for example, with `overflow: auto`.  This way, when the new content is appended to this div, it'll have a scrollbar added to it. Bind your event to the 'onscroll' of this div, not the page. When you scroll below this div, you'll get the div you were trying to scroll to.

Comment: fun fact: infinite scroll has no "after". It's infinite scroll. If you have any important elements after it, you're doing infinite scroll wrong, so the problem you're trying to solve is one caused by your choice of visual presentation. Fix that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the div is being loaded dynamically with infinite scroll then it probably doesn't exist in the DOM at the time the page is loaded. If this is the case, then you'll need to write some code that executes the infinite scroll to load the required content into the DOM. If the user's browser hasn't requested the div, how do you expect it to be there?

Answer (score 0):

A crude way of doing what you want, without restructuring your views is to just continually execute the infinite scroll code until you find the div you want. This would not be ideal though as you are forcing the browser to load up a lot of content and you also run the risk that the div in the query string does not exist!

You might have to rethink the way you are directing users to your content. Is it possible for you to just have a one page view that displays the piece of content by itself or would it lose all meaning if it wasn't embedded amongst all of the other content?